# Same command run via bash and Java's ProcessBuilder api gets different output

Tags: java, git, stdout, git-bash, processbuilder

So I'm trying to run a Git command through java. I'm currently on Windows with the git bash interface and Java 8 installed.

When I run this command through git bash : `git --git-dir=PathToMyGitRepo log --pretty=format:'{"commit":"%H"},%n'` I get a JSON formated output of all my logs on this repository, thus making the parsing easy. The generated JSON look like this

```
{"commit":"SHA1"},
{"commit":"SHA2"}, 
...
```

So then I ported the command to my Java application and used the **ProcessBuilder** api to run the previous command. The command run without throwing any exception, but the output I get with the getInputStream method return something like this

```
'{commit:SHA1},''{commit:SHA2},'
```

which is not a valid JSON string. The single quotes were keept the double quotes were thrown even the next line characters were lost somewhat.

I tried printing the exact same command just befrore **ProcessBuilder** runs it and then run it my self. Even the redirected output of the command to a file via bash and via Java provide different results.

Does someone have a clue of what's going on here ? I suspect Java making some sort of tweaks and twist to run an external program, but I don't understand how it affect the output of the said program.

-----------------------------------------------------------------EDIT------------------------------------------------------------

So as requested this is the code of the code of how I get the InputStream:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = null
try{
    List<String> gitCommand = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("git", "--git-dir=PathToMyGitRepo", "log", "--pretty=format:'{\"commit\":\"%H\"},%n'"));
    Process p = new ProcessBuilder(gitCommand).start();
    bis = (BufferedInputStream) p.getInputStream();
    String buff = "";
    String JSON = "";
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bis));
    while((buff = bis.readLine())!=null){
        JSON += buff;
    }
    System.out.println(JSON);
}catch(IOException ex){
  ...
}
```

I don't do anything beside parsing the `JSON` string i get back. But then I get a `ParsingError: Unexpected character (') at position 1.`. I'm using the SimpleJSON library for my JSON related stuff.

Comment: Posting your code would help out here ... how are you obtaining the `InputStream`, are you wrapping it with a `Reader` type class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you did not convert it correctly. Java runs a shell underneath and the latter can strip quotes before executing your command. Depending on the shell, it might allow you to escape the quotes. You might be able go save them, using enough back slashes in java command line, something like `"git...{\\\"command\\\"..."` or even more back slashes, or a combination of single and double quotes.

To make life portable and easier I suggest to forget about the quotes and place them in the result. For example you can pass some other symbol: `--pretty=format:'{=commit=:=%H=},%n` and then just run `result.replaceAll("=","\"");` or something else

Comment: I tried the single quote technique but the results stayed the same. For your solution, it seems like a bit hacky way of doing things... I like it! I will return to you about this technique if nothing else work.